# Retarder potential strange derivation

Tags: electromagnetism, potential, lienard-wiechert

I have an old French textbook (the author died a few years ago) that develops in quite a very very detailed way the relativist Larmor formula on more than 35 pages.

However, I've been stuck for a few days on a step that may be obvious (...). Here is the figure used by the author:

[image]

And at a given moment he writes ($\vec{\nabla}$ is the nabla operator):

$$\vec{\nabla}\bigg(z-\frac{\vec{z}\cdot\vec{v}}{c}\bigg)=\frac{\vec{z}}{z}-\frac{\vec{z}}{z}\frac{v}{c}=\frac{\vec{z}}{z}-\hat{r}\frac{v}{s}=\frac{\vec{z}}{z}-\frac{\vec{v}}{c}$$

The thing is:

1. I don't understand the steps (and I'm not able to identify the missing steps too).
2. Sadly he never defined earlier what is $\hat{r}$

So I have to guess but I've been stuck for two weeks. If maybe someone has an idea...?

Comment: What is $s$? ...

Comment: It’s $s=z-(\vec{z}\vec{v})/c$

Comment: That belongs in the question.

Comment: No. I know where the $s$ comes from however.... i also don’t understand how he makes it appear in the above equalities....

Comment: Without an explanation of $s$, the question lacks clarity. Your question is supposed to be understandable by anyone reading it. This site is not here to answer questions for *you*. It is here to be a Q&A resource for *all*. Since you have not clarified the question, I have voted to close it as unclear.

Comment: I will translate all the pages of the book this week related to that topic (5 pages) and put it here. Thx for your patience

Comment: Here is a retranscription as requested: https://www.dropbox.com/s/s0szcqhfdi6j4lt/Rayonnement_Charge_Acceleree.pdf?dl=0

Comment: As I read the comments, no one ever requested a "retranscription," the request was simply that you add the information that $s = z - (\vec z \vec v)/c$ to the body of your question... And while you are at it maybe explain what $\vec z \vec v$ means... is it supposed to be a dot product?

Comment: I think more information needs to be ported from the dropbox link into the actual body of the question before you will get an answer...

Comment: The s doesn’t mean anithying physically. It’s just a variable for notation simplification purpose. And yes it’s a dot product.

Answer (score 0):

To answer question 2: $\hat r$ is a common notation for unit vectors (vectors with length 1). They are defined as
$$\hat r=\frac{1}{r}\vec r$$
To answer your first question consider what the nabla operator does. In this case it's a gradient so it takes in a function and spits out a vector containing the derivatives of that function:
$$\nabla f(x,y,z)=\pmatrix{\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\\\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\\\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}}$$
Because our function only depends on $z$ we can see that the $x$, $y$ compontents of the gradient will be zero and we can just look at the $z$ component. So you can probably calculate
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial z}\left(z-\frac{\vec z\cdot \vec v}{c}\right)=\frac{\partial}{\partial z}\left(z-\frac{z\, v_z}{c}\right)$$
We can write a vector generally as follows
$$\vec v=v_x\hat x+v_y\hat y+v_z\hat z$$
So since the $x,y$ components of our gradient are zero the expression becomes
$$\nabla \left(z-\frac{\vec z\cdot \vec v}{c}\right)=\hat z\left[\frac{\partial}{\partial z}\left(z-\frac{\vec z\cdot \vec v}{c}\right)\right]$$

Comment: « The function depends only on $z$ ». How did you deduce that from the figure ? O_o

Comment: @VincentISOZ Actually I didn't look at the figure. I just looked at the first equation you typed. The term that nabla acts on only depends on $z$.

Comment: @VincentISOZ It's not possible for me to follow the steps after the first equal sign either. It seems like the author uses some approximations/simplifications but without the book I have no idea what he did.

Comment: Thx for trying anyway. It’s also a pain in the ass for me a friend mathematician. We were not able to guess what he is doing here... sad that the author died....